# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Доброго времени суток!
Напомните, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "как" в след. выражениях:
"Жила как все. Была как все".
Является ли здесь оборот "как все" частью сказуемого? Или это сравнение - также, как все?
Заранее большое спасибо.
С уважением, Ольга.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении "Жила, как все" запятая нужна, так как это сложное предложение с придаточным сравнительным, ср.: "Жила, как все живут". Во втором предложении "Была как все" запятая не нужна, "как все" здесь часть сказуемого.

Answer (score 1):

**Жила как все. Была как все**. Оборот является именной частью сказуемого или обстоятельством, тесно связанным со сказуемым, запятая не нужна

Я **жил как все**, не лучше и не хуже, Под следствием ни разу не бывал, На стройках века был стране я нужен И шел, куда нас кормчий посылал.

Он **жил как все**. Как все, недоедал. Как все, вздыхал над невеселой сводкой.

Оставь, и я **была как все**, И хуже всех была, Купалась я в чужой росе, И пряталась в чужом овсе, В чужой траве спала (Анна Ахматова).

Но:  **Я жил**, как все, **в греховной суете**, Не мучился, я совестью, в грехе. Грехи я пил, черпая в полноте, Смеясь идя, к погибельной черте.

Здесь оборот обособляется, основное содержание "жил в греховной суете".